# how to create a grid of plots in Bokeh w/ some empty cell(s)

Tags: python, bokeh

I am aware of 2 different ways to group plots together in Bokeh:  Grid and HBox/VBox.  I want to have a general way of creating an n x m grid, where some cells of the grid can be empty.  For example, if each X is a plot figure, might want to have:

```
X X X
  X
X X X
```

I have not found a general way to do this.  Assuming I have created plots with:

```
import numpy as np
import bokeh.plotting as bp
from bokeh.models import GridPlot

bp.output_file("/tmp/test.html", "test")

def random_plot (width, height, k=100):
    x = np.arange(k)
    y = np.random.normal(size=k)
    plot = bp.figure (
        plot_width=width, plot_height=height, title=None,
        toolbar_location=None)
    plot.line(x,y)
    return plot

UL = random_plot(width=300, height=400)
UR = random_plot(width=600, height=400)
LL = random_plot(width=300, height=200)
LR = random_plot(width=600, height=200)
```

I cannot use GridPlot (to my knowledge) to create a plot with just:

```
UL UR
   LR
```

The following does not work:

```
grid = GridPlot(children=[[UL, UR], [None, LR]])
bp.show (grid)
```

I could use a composition of HBox and VBox to achieve the simple layout above:

```
left = bp.VBox(children=[UL])
right = bp.VBox(children=[UR,LR])
combined = bp.HBox (children=[left,right])
bp.show(combined)
```

however, cannot handle more complex cases such as the 3 x 3 configuration shown above.

I want the figures to align.  Can I put an invisible element into the grid to satisfy a missing cell?  And if so, how?

**Update**
As it happens, someone else has requested this on the Bokeh mailing list (and it does not seem to be currently supported).  Hopefully will soon become a new feature of GridPlot.

Comment: Some improvements for this will be in an upcoming 0.7.1 release, but the major solution will be in 0.8 in mid Feb 2015. Some immediate workarounds are discussed here: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/1620

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bokeh 0.7.1 (to be released next Monday) will allow `None` in the grid pot specification.

Comment: Additional note: it seems, though, that rows or columns with all `None`s in the gridplot will be ignored.